# NBHM 2016 linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the statement true?

> If $v$ be a vector space over $\mathbb R^5$ with usual inner product, and $W$ and $Z$ are subspaces of $V$ both with dimension 3, then there exists $z\in Z$ such that $z\ne\mathbf 0$ and $z$ is orthogonal to $W$.

Comment: Do you mean "let $V$ be $\mathbb{R}^5$ with its usual inner product", when you write "If $v$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}^5$ with usual inner product"?

Comment: I have assumed it was that, too.

Comment: Sir I can not understand here what is the relation between Z and orthogonal complement of W . As there have non empty intersection. But how can I get the dimention of(Z+ orthogonal complement of W ) and dimension of (Z intersection with orthogonal complement of W)

Answer (score 0):

There exists such a $z \in Z$ iff the intersection between $Z$ and the orthogonal of $W$ is non equal to zero.

The orthogonal of $W$ is of dimension $5-3 =2$. Since $Z$ is of dimension $3$, there is no reason such a $z$ have to exist (it would have been the case if the sum of the two dimensions was $> 5$).

You can think about two planes in $\mathbb R^3$, it's almost the same situation.